# Как переименовать по маске несколько файлов?

Tags: cmd, bat

Есть файлы:

```
aaaaa-max.jpg
bbbbbbbb-max.jpg
cccc-max.png
```

должно быть так:

```
aaaaa.jpg
bbbbbbbb.jpg
cccc.png
```

пытался сделать так, но не работает:

```
@echo off
for %%A IN (*.jpg *.png) DO (
 for /f "tokens=1* delims='-max'" %%B IN ("%%~A") DO ren %%~A %%~B%%~xA
)
echo on
```

Comment: Нужно не дублировать вопрос несколько раз, а привлекать внимание к первоначальному вопросу.

Comment: ок, пытался привлекать внимание со вчерашнего дня

Comment: Вопрос чуть чуть отличается от предыдущего тем, что оказалось "префикс" может иметь переменную длинну, поэтому автор задаёт новый вопрос.  Отредактируйте этот вопрос, что б назывался "перереименовать по маске с разделителем". Или как то так что б было видно отличие.понятно что вопросы разные.

Comment: Как это решить? подскажите плз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам известен удаляемый фрагмент, тогда проще его заменить на пустое

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For %%F in (*-max.jpg, *-max.png) do (
Set file=%%~F
Echo !file:-max=!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, то так:

```
For %%F in (*.jpg, *.png) do (
For /F "delims='-'" %%B in ("%%~F") do (
Echo %%B%%~xF%
)
)
```

Comment: правильно поняли, но ваше решение не будет работать, если в имени файла несколько дефисов `-`

Comment: подскажите плз, как это решить?

Comment: @word, про несколько дефисов речи не было. А вам именно на cmd нужно решать? Сейчас же современные технологии есть, например начиная с win10 командной средой является powershell

Comment: такое решение, которое в ответе не отличается от моего решения, по логике вещей файлы могут иметь несколько дефисов. про powershell также речи не было. Подскажите плз, как решить это на cmd?

Comment: а потом говорят, чтобы не засорять тему :), когда уже я две темы создал, комментариев не по теме больше чем ответов

Comment: Ладно, начнем сначала. Вам нужно удалить текст в имени файла после последнего дефиса до расширения? Вы этот текст знаете? У вас в примере везде '-max' написано.

Comment: да, нужно удалить текст `-max` перед расширением файла, но дефисов может быть много в имени файла

Comment: я так понял на cmd такое сделать нельзя?